# How do you level up your Spartan to level 50 quickly

Tags: halo-4

I need to level up because I've been playing for a year and I'm still at level 6 and all my friends are at level 129 and they don't think I'm good enough

Comment: Level merely mean how long youve played.  Considering you need skill to play...

Comment: Have you been playing only Custom Games and Campaign? You need to do online games for any reasonable amount of EXP.

Answer (score 1):

Plays Spartan Ops missions on legendary, I went from level 1 to 10 in 15 minutes (you may want some of your friends to help)

Answer (score 0):

With a total of 130 ranks in Halo 4's Multiplayer, you can expect to play a little longer than you'd like in order to hit the level capacity.

Unfortunately for those wishing to reach the highest rank within a day, Halo 4 has a daily XP limit of 150,000 XP. After this amount of XP has been earned in a single day, no more XP can be earned from matches, Challenges, or Commendations. The daily limit resets at around 2:00AM PST (5:00AM EST) along with the daily challenges.

Every set of 10 ranks beyond SR-50 requires the same amount of XP to rank up. This means 50-60 will take the same amount of XP as 60-70. Beyond SR-50, Specializations are used. When a player opts for one Specialization they may not opt for another until they rank up 10 times. There are a total of eight Specializations, making the level cap SR-130.

**Here Are Your Options:**

**Spartan Ops** 
Spartan Ops rewards players with loads of XP, especially when played in Matchmaking. Spartan Ops matchmaking rewards players with about twice the amount of XP than a normal Spartan Ops match. Search for a match through matchmaking, and you're guaranteed to earn 5,950xp. The amount of XP earned through a Spartan Ops match depends entirely on the amount of time spent in that match. The amount awarded is capped out at 5,950xp (11,900 with DewXP), and this is given out for about ten minutes of gameplay

**War Games:**
Although based on personal preference, each playlist in Halo 4 will award players with the same amount of XP, or close to the same amount. This means that the playlists which provide the shortest games will provide the most XP over an amount of time. The playlists which provide the shortest games are:

- Regicide
- Oddball
- King of the Hill
- Flood
- Dominion

If you feel another playlist is providing you with more XP over time, then stick with that playlist. Most of the XP rewarded at the end of the match is earned from winning the match, so stick with what you're best at.

**Waypoint Terminal Codes**
They offer a wide range of awards to those willing to solve a couple riddles. The codes can be found at the page linked [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Waypoint_Terminal_Codes), and can be entered through the Xbox 360 Waypoint app. Some of the codes offer players loads of XP for redeeming them. So far a total of 19,116xp can be earned from these codes. Though there are requirements to be met before they can be redeemed.